# Finding where a variable or object was declared Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

In Netbeans PHP if you control + mouse1 click on an object or variable it will go to the initial declaration, if it's in the same script.

But is there any way to make it go to the initial declaration if it was made inside a previously included script?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but this is my work around:

1. **Select** or highlight the variable.
2. **Right click** > Refactor > Rename...
3. Change the name.
4. **Click** the `Preview` button

Netbeans will then list all the occurrences of the variable within your project. From this list, you should be able to find where you initialized it.

Be sure to **click** the `Cancel` button, if you do not mean to rename the variable.

For the same results without refactoring, you can also use **Edit** > **Find Usages**.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. Your method is a bit like the 'find usages' option, and would probably work in most instances but I have an enormous framework here with a number of global variables being used hundreds of times across numerous scripts, and working out where each had been instantiated is proving to be problematic.

Comment: Ah. The **Edit** > **Find Usages** option is much simpler than what I suggested, although the result is effectively the same.

Comment: hmm looks like it's not possible, so I might consider changing IDE's as this is a pretty big issue for me at the moment